# Can you use MongoDB with Firebase Hosting?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mongodb-atlas

So I'm making a web app with React, Next.js and MongoDB and I'm looking at hosting it on Firebase.

I heard it has it's own [built in database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) similar to MongoDB, but it [doesn't have text search](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Firestore%20doesn%27t%20support,%2Dside%20isn%27t%20practical.) which is a significant drawback for what I want to make.

I was wondering if it's possible to run MongoDB natively on Firebase, or if not, if I can just use MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Hosting only serves static assets itself. It does not run any code you might have in those files, so it is not possible to run MongoDB directly on Firebase Hosting.

Accessing the cloud-hosted MongoDB *is* possible. The how depends on where the code that accesses MongoDB is run:

- If you want to access MongoDB directly from the client-side code (through [Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/realm) it seems), you can host that client-side code on Firebase Hosting without any additional steps.
- If you want to access MongoDB from server-side code, that isn't directly built into Firebase Hosting, but you can use its integration with [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions) and [Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) to accomplish it.

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "only serves static assets". Does that still allow me to run a Next.js server?

Comment: Since Next.js requires the JavaScript code to be run on the server, it can't be served by _just_ Firebase Hosting. But if you use the integrations in my second bullet point, then it becomes possible since they allow running Node.js code on Google's servers.

Comment: Firebase has now added 'Web Frameworks.' With Web Frameworks enabled `firebase deploy` automatically creates Firebase functions to serve server-side rendered components.
View here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/frameworks/nextjs

Answer (score 1):

You can do text search in Firebase + Firestore using a 3rd party tool and link is here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search .

Firebase can be used with MongoDB. Also, you can use MongoDB from Atlas or you can run it on GCP servers itself. Check GCP marketplace for easy installation of MongoDB.

Comment: I would still prefer to use MongoDB because I've already written my API but thanks for the latter info.